# Double key dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, dataset, key

I am performing some computations and I'm sure there is a better way to store the information I have than what I'm currently doing.

Currently, I have a dictionary of dictionaries of the form

`mydict[timestep][node] = {'property1' : value, 'property2' : value, ...}`

This data structure is fine when I want to have a full picture of all nodes at a certain timestep, e.g `mydict[timestep] = {'node1': {...}, 'node2': {...}, ...}`. However, it is a bit annoying when I need the opposite: given a certain node, retrieve a dictionary of what happens to it at each timestep. Something like `mydict[node] = {'timestep1': {...}, 'timestep2' : {...}, ...}` would be awesome.

I can manually code a workaround, however I feel that there should be a better way to do so. I've seen similar questions online whose solution was having tuples as single keys, however I don't think that is suitable for me.

I've considered using a Pandas dataframe but I am not sure about it, as during the computations `mydict` is constantly being changed and my experience is that such dataframes are more suitable for static datasets.

Please let me know any ideas you might have, and thanks for your time!

Comment: looks like a database (sqlite?) might be appropriate

Comment: Yeah I also think a database would be fine, but wouldn't it be a bit of an overkill? Also, some of the values I need to store are lists, and that is not a native datatype there.

Comment: Another way out can be maintaining two dicts in case you want to avoid using any database. One being `mydict[timestep][node]` and another `mydict2[node[[timestep]` and keep the writes in sync whenever you are doing them, twice the memory but all your queries would be optimized.
But for larger data using something like in-memory sqlite is a good idea.

Comment: Dataframe would be nice and should solve your problems